# Identifying the indices of any one of the elements that have max value in a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, max

Suppose there's a 2D array in python. I only need to find the index of an element that has the highest value.

However, there could be multiple elements that have the highest value. My objective is to find the index of any one of them, and the preference is to reduce time and space complexity.

How do I do this?

One way is to find the max value of the array. Then I compare every element in the array that matches the max value and get the index of the element that matches first. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Following is the code I'm currently using

```
myarray = np.array([[0] * c for i in range(r)]) #r and c are number of rows and columns
max_myarray = np.argmax(myarray)
for i in range(r):
  for j in range(c):
    if (myarray[i][j]==max_myarray):
      row_index=i
      column_index=j
```

Comment: Are you using Numpy?

Comment: @Billa okay, I'm slightly new to this forum, I'll upload it asap. Sorry about that

Comment: @NilsWerner yes, I'll upload my code so that'll give a better context

Comment: @Billa just uploaded

Comment: You should really learn more about NumPy. You don't seem to understand what `argmax()` does, and the first line can be replaced with `myarray = numpy.zeros((c, r))`... which obviously is a really bad example when you're looking for maxima in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to get the index ( "j" ) of the max element on each row. and choose the row that have the maximum element in the 2D array. 
Below is a sample code you may find it useful:

**N.B** : this code is written in python 3 if you are using python 2.7 just change the print statement.

```
my_array=[[1,3,4],[5,7,6],[7,3,4]]
max_i=0
max_element=0
max_j=0
i=0
for row in my_array:
    if max(row)>max_element:
        max_j=row.index( max(row) )
        max_i=i
        max_element=max(row)
    i+=1
print(max_i,max_j)
```

Comment: But what if there are two elements with max value and they lie in the same row?

Comment: It will return the index of the first element with max value in the row

Comment: I keep getting this error for the line max_j=row.index(max(row));                                     

    
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Also, what if I simply use row.index(np.argmax(my_array)), and there are multiple elements that have max value, which index will it output?

Comment: It looks like calling index by row.index works only for lists. What do you use in case its an array?

Comment: I am not used with np.argmax() function. However I think you will find this link useful : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Comment: Khelifi Aymen: Your `print` statement/calls will work fine in Python 3 because you included the `()` around the arguments—it will just print the two values as a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

You need any of the maximum positions? To get the **first one**

```
numpy.unravel_index(numpy.argmax(A), A.shape))  # (4, 0)
```

Your example code however always finds the **last occurrence**, which can be done using

```
numpy.unravel_index(A.size - 1 - numpy.argmax(A[::-1, ::-1]), A.shape)  # (4, 4)
```